# Language for Google Voice Actions queries

Tags: android, google-search, google-voice-actions

I made a demo app in Android with Kotlin and Google Voices Action to allow me to search in an app after a "Ok Google" (SEARCH_ACTION). It works perfectly well when I said

> "Search **this thing** in **my app name**"

But doesn't work when I said it in french.

I tried to:

- set up my default research language in french
- delete others recognizable languages
- set up the region in France
- create a second strings.xml for a french version

Is it actually possible to use an other language then english to execute an action in an app from the voice api ? If yes, how ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my answer [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2940021?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).

> **Where you can use voice search**
>
> These actions are available in English in the United States, United Kingdom, Australia, Canada, India, Ireland, Singapore, and South Africa.